# IOException in okHttp only for android 5+ devices

Tags: android, okhttp

In android 5.1.1 (Moto G 3) call to the url "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/73350021/posts/60915" gave exception `android java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR`. The same works fine in devices with older OS.The stacktrace is :

```
10-05 20:32:41.195 15373-15373/? D/NetworkError﹕ stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR
java.io.IOException: stream was reset: PROTOCOL_ERROR
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.SpdyStream.getResponseHeaders(SpdyStream.java:145)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SpdyTransport.readResponseHeaders(SpdyTransport.java:104)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:830)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:95)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:823)
at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:684)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:272)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
```

Has anyone using okHttp client faced the same issue. Please let me know if you could resolve it.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: two of my libraries contain okhttp I remove one and sync . Now working fine.